# Android, viewing SQLite database in runtime (not like other questions)

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

So i have been looking for this answer for the past 2 days. all of them want to know how to extract the database file .sql from the device your testing your app on. What i want to do is use a manager, like fire fox's sqlite manager, to open the location of the file and view the data base as information is being entered. I did this once when i was using titanium, but now have switched to eclipse. So what i want is, when i am running my virtual machine, android emulator, i want to fine the location that it is reading the sql file from. doing this i can open it with my fire fox manager and as info is going into the file the manager will show me whats going in and out. Basically i want to see real time info from my internal database, either from emulator or phone. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: You can use sqlite3 to view the database, but I believe it won't show data changes once you open the .db file. You will probably have to close and re open the database.

Comment: viewing the file is not the problem it is finding it on my computer, mac. Do you know were the emulator puts the sql file on the computer?

Comment: do `adb shell` from terminal and navigate to your package inside `/data/data/your.package/databases`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [this link](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/) and get the SQLiteManager plugin for eclipse.

Comment: I LOVE YOU! that was the right one but does not work anymore the update is here https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4r4Yoc9-rj3NXRacmh5QTBnUG8/edit

Comment: Updated, eh?  Got it!